# How can I operate on elements of a data.frame in r, that creates a new column?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, aggregate

Suppose I have a data.frame, df.

```
a b d
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 2 6
2 1 5
2 3 6
2 1 1
```

I'd like to operate on it so that for all places where a and b are equal, I compute the mean of d.

I found that using aggregate can do this,
aggregate(d ~ a + b, df, mean)
This gives me something reasonable

```
a b d
1 2 5
2 1 3
2 3 6
```

But I would ideally like to keep my original d column, and add a new column m, so that I get the original data.frame with a new column "m" that contains the averages like,

```
a b d m
1 2 4 5
1 2 5 5
1 2 6 5
2 1 5 3
2 3 6 6
2 1 1 3
```

Any ideas on how to do this "properly" in R?

Comment: You are looking for `ave` as in `with(df, ave(d, a, b))`

Comment: using `data.table`: `setDT(df)[,m:=mean(d), by=list(a,b)][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "a b d
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 2 6
2 1 5
2 3 6
2 1 1
" , header = T)


df %>% 
  group_by(a , b)  %>%
  mutate(m = mean(d))
```